# 802.11 HT Capabilities IE vs. HT Information IE

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11

I have a Wireshark capture of an 802.11 beacon. I am looking at the "HT Capabilities" and "HT Information" sections. Both contain the following information element: "Rx Modulation and Coding Scheme: [Basic] MCS Set". However, their values differ.

Why do they differ? What is the difference between these two information elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *HT Capabilities* section provides the MCS values which are supported by the wireless network.  These data rates can be used by both the AP and the client to send unicast traffic back and forth.

The *HT Information* section contains the *Basic Data Rates* supported (if any).  The *Basic Data Rates* will be a subset of the supported data rates and are used for broadcast, multicast and management traffic.